# Build a report with SQL with combining columns and rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019, string-aggregation

Here is my table:

Table Purchase Report

| PURC_ID | CUS_ID | Product | QTY | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Leg_01 | 2 | 2021-04-09 |
| 2 | John | Head_01 | 1 | 2021-04-09 |
| 3 | Dawn | Head_01 | 1 | 2021-04-09 |
| 4 | Dawn | Shoulder_01 | 2 | 2021-04-09 |
| 5 | Dawn | Leg_01 | 1 | 2021-04-09 |
| 6 | Keith | Leg_01 | 2 | 2021-04-09 |

I would like to build the report as follow:

Table 4: (PURC table will combine with other columns. I need Product Code follow by underscore follow by qty).

| REP_ID | Cust | PURC | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Head_01_1, Leg_01_2 | 2021-04-09 |
| 2 | Dawn | Head_01_1, Shoulder_01_2, Leg_01_1 | 2021-04-09 |
| 3 | Keith | Leg_01_2 | 2021-04-09 |

I know how to join table, but I'm not sure how to combine in this format. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer might be product specific.)

Comment: This can be done with group_concat in MySQL.

Comment: Sql express 2019

Comment: See `STRING_AGG()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should give you the desired output

```
select row_number() over(order by avg(purc_id)) REP_ID,
  CUS_ID Cust,
  string_agg(product + '_' + cast(Qty as varchar(2)),', ') PURC,
  [Date]
from PurchaseReport
group by CUS_ID, [Date]
```

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thank you everyone for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  Cust, STRING_AGG(Product + '_' + CAST(QTY AS varchar(10)), ', ') AS PURC, Date 
FROM PURC_Table 
GROUP BY Cust, Date
```

Note: `STRING_AGG()` is supported on SQL Server 2017 and later.

Answer (score 0):

The first column seems to be based on the minimum `purc_id`.  For the concatenated column, the other answers are fine, but `concat()` is more convenient:

```
select row_number() over (order by min(purc_id)) as rep_id
       cus_id as Cust,
       string_agg(concat(product, '_', qty), ', ') as purc,
       [Date]
from PurchaseReport
group by cus_id, [Date]
```